# CSS Transition: one transform property, not the other

Tags: html, css

I am running into an issue right now. I have an element that I drag around the screen. When I switch directions (left or right), I tilt it the direction it is heading (giving it a feeling of gravity happening to it.

In order to make the tilting smooth, I apply the following css to it:

```
transition: all linear 50ms;
```

And then, I just switch the transform property to rotate it left or right, using the following:

```
transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(<x under mouse>px) translateY(<y under mouse>px);
```

The problem is that I want to have the transition on the rotate, but not on the translateX or translateY. It is making the translateX/translateY look choppy.

Is it possible to have a transition for one part of the transform property, but not the other? Or should I set the X/Y using the `top` and `left` properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an ideal solution (from a purist's point of view), but have you considered wrapping the element inside another and just applying the transform to that one?

Comment: That's a pretty smart answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I am going to give it a go. Funny how the simplest answers are the best ones.

Comment: Would still be interested in a purist solution just for knowledge :)

Comment: Not wrapping it in markup, but later in JavaScript. ;) Or doing some kind of CSS parsing voodoo.

Comment: I used the old Jeopardy strategy. ;) Seriously, though: it *is* an answer. Just worded as a question. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: For "purists", I think this is one use case for the upcoming Web Animations API spec. See the [polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) for details.